# Como passar um parâmetro de uma Activity b para Activity A

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Boa noite, preciso de ajuda para resolver o seguinte problema, estou fazendo um jogo estilo Show do Milhão. Tenho uma Activity principal que é onde ocorre as perguntas e tem os botões que acionam as ajudas. Quando o usuário clica no botão das cartas, abre uma segunda Activity (detalhe, a Activity principal continua aberta), ao gerar a carta eu preciso passar o valor dessa carta para Activity principal.

O problema é que se eu usar o código abaixo:

**Obs: Esse código é usado na Activity 2, que seria uma tela temporária que executa um código e volta para Tela Principal**

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, TelaPrincipal.class);`

`intent.putExtras("valor", valor);` // valor é o atributo que preciso passar para tela principal.

`startActivity(intent);`

Eu vou está reiniciando a Activity principal, e não posso fazer isso, pois estaria perdendo o andamento do jogo. Então preciso passar esse parâmetro de outra forma.

Detalhe, não tenho muita experiencia estou começando a programar nessa plataforma, então quem puder mandar uma resposta detalhada agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar os métodos da Activity Result API pra isso. Realmente, se você chama um `startActivityForResult` na segunda Activity, a primeira Activity vai ser iniciada do zero, e não é o que você quer (inclusive, a animação de transição entre essas telas também vai dar a entender que você tá "indo" pra essa tela ao invés de "voltando").

Pra fazer o que você quer, você precisa usar outro conjunto de métodos. Considerando que você quer enviar o ID da carta clicada (como int) pra segunda Activity, e que você precisa retornar esse "valor" como String, você precisa definir uma classe de contrato pra essa troca de informações entre as Activities:

```
class MyContract : ActivityResultContract<Int, String>() {
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, cardId: Int) =
        Intent(context, SecondActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(CARD_ID_EXTRA, cardId)
        }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): String? {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return null
        }

        return intent?.getStringExtra(VALUE_EXTRA)
    }

    companion object {
        const val CARD_ID_EXTRA = "card_id"
        const val VALUE_EXTRA = "valor"
    }
}
```

Essa classe define que você vai passar um Int e receber uma String de volta. Veja onde o Intent é criado e como o "valor" vai ser extraído do Intent de retorno. Isso vai ser feito implicitamente no seu código principal, porque já tá definido aqui.

Agora, na sua MainActivity, crie uma instância desse contrato entre as duas Activities:

```
val contractLauncher = registerForActivityResult(MyContract()) { str ->
    // faça o que quiser com str, que é "valor" retornado pela segunda Activity
}
```

Esse `contractLauncher` vai ser usado pra iniciar a segunda Activity. Então, no clique do botão da carta, você vai chamar o seguinte código:

```
contractLauncher.launch(cardId)
```

Isso vai criar um Intent com esse `cardId` e abrir a segunda Activity com ele. Tudo como já foi definido na classe `MyContract`.

Agora, na sua segunda Activity, você precisa pegar o valor da carta:

```
val cardId = intent.extras?.getInt(MyContract.CARD_ID_EXTRA) ?: -1
```

O valor de `cardId` vai ser o que foi passado lá na MainActivity (ou -1, se alguém iniciar essa segunda Activity sem passar um valor pro `cardID`).

E ainda nessa segunda Activity, na hora que a pessoa escolher o "valor", você precisa fazer o seguinte pra indicar que é pra retornar ele:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent().apply {
    putExtra(MyContract.VALUE_EXTRA, valor)
})
finish()
```

Esse `finish()` vai finalizar a segunda Activity e voltar pra MainActivity (e não iniciar a MainActivity de novo) e vai passar esse valor de volta pra ela. Aquele callback com `str` definido lá em cima, na hora que você criou o `contractLauncher`, vai ser chamado e você vai poder usar esse valor de volta na MainActivity. A animação de transição agora vai ser como se você tivesse "voltando" pra Activity anterior, que é o que você quer.

Veja mais detalhes sobre isso na documentação oficial em: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: Bom dia amigo, cara agradeço por sua ajuda. Bem esclarecedor o texto. Eu até consegui resolver o problema antes da sua resposta. Eu consegui duas formas.

A primeira eu gerei o sorteio do valor a ser exibido na carta e consequentemente na eliminação das respostas erradas, na tela principal. E como ela já fazia um intent chamando a tela Cartas, eu passei esse valor como extra e na tela carta eu pego esse valor e independente da carta que o usuário clique o sorteio já havia sido definido....

Comment: A segunda abordagem que fiz foi criar um método dentro da Activity Cartas fazer o sorteio lá, e na Activity Tela Principal eu instanciei a Activity Cartas como objeto e acessei o método puxando o valor sorteado. Também deu certo... Porem há uma falha em ambas as opções e queria aproveitar o seu conhecimento para ver se resolvo.

Qauando estou executando um bloco de comando Ex: Ao clicar em um botão ele toca um som, gera o sorteio do valor das cartas, chama a Activity Cartas aonde aconteceria a parte visual que mostra a carta sorteada...

Comment: Porém antes de chamar essa Activity Cartas ele tbm executa o comando que elimina as opções erradas fazendo com que o usuário veja isso antes do sorteio das cartas. Esse comando só deveria ser executado após a chamada da Activity Cartas que é fechada automaticamente assim que o usuário escolhe a carta, então apenas aí, ele retornaria para a Activity Tela Principal e continuaria o curso do comando.

Comment: Não sei se conseguir ser claro, mas o que está acontecendo de forma resumida, é que quando executo um comando que deveria ocorrer em partes, eu vejo tudo ocorrendo de uma vez, mesmo se eu criar um método que gere um sleep entre um comando e outro dentro do mesmo trecho de código isso não é respeitado, ele gera todo o código e a pausa do sleep só acontece depois de tudo executado.

Comment: Imagine um comando que tivesse que mostrar de 0 a 10 tendo 1 segundo de tempo entre cada. Ele geraria todos os números e só no final ele daria a pausa de 1 segundo... mais ou menos isso! Sabe como posso resolver?